# File doesn′t get into the commit after using git add -N

Tags: git

I want to commit a Python module’s `__init__.py` file, which, on my disk, already contains code. However, for the current commit, I wanted to add it empty, as this part of the code is yet to be tested. Thus, I used

```
$ git add -N __init__.py
```

The file is there in the output of `git status`, but if I issue `git commit`, all other files gets into the commit except `__init__.py`, which, in turn, remains in the index according to `git status`.

The man page of `git-add` says for `-N` that

```
Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no content.
```

Is there a way to circumvent this `will be added later` part, i.e. add the file empty without temporarily deleting its content?

**Edit:** This happens with current (2.2.0) Git. With 1.7.1 and a small test repo, I get an error:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   b
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   b
#
$ git commit -m 'test'
b: not added yet
error: Error building trees
```

Comment: I believe you need to run git commit with ````-a```` when you use the ````-N```` flag on add. From the help: *This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files with git diff and committing them with git commit -a.*

Comment: That’s a no-go, because it will commit all other modified files, regardless if I added them with `git add` or not. Untracked files, however, will still remain untracked this way.

Comment: That's hilarious. When only using `git add -N` and then commiting you can create a completly empty commit. Just wanted to share that little gem.

Comment: You can use `git add -p` after `git add -N` and simply decline adding the single diff hunk you are asked about.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4232334/279627) for more information.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I've actually tried that and at least in git 1.9.4 that won't solve the issue.

Comment: @Zeeker: Fair enough -- it worked for me at the time I wrote the linked answer, which also provides alternative approaches of achieving the same thing.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thank you, my search-fu failed me to find that post, which makes my question somewhat a duplicate of that one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can git commit "empty versions" of new files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232171/can-git-commit-empty-versions-of-new-files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed with Git 2.5 (Q2 2015), meaning `git commit` won't try to include the new file "intended to be added later".
See [commit d95d728](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d95d728aba06a34394d15466045cbdabdada58a2) by Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy ([`pclouds`](https://github.com/pclouds)) (merged in [d0c692263](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0c692263f453f267ddd82b90b1a2fcff9d45f5f))

> ### `diff-lib.c`: adjust position of `i-t-a` entries in `diff`

#### Problem:

> Entries added by "`git add -N`" are reminder for the user so that they don't forget to add them before committing. These entries appear in the index even though they are not real.
>   Their presence in the index leads to a confusing "`git status`" like this:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
        new file:   foo

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   foo
```

> If you do a "`git commit`", "`foo`" will not be included even though
>   "`status`" reports it as "`to be committed`".

#### Solution:

> This patch changes the output to become

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
        new file:   foo

no changes added to commit
```

In other words:

> - Treat such paths as "yet to be added to the index but Git already know about them";
> - "`git diff HEAD`" and "`git diff --cached HEAD`" should not talk about them, and
> - "`git diff`" should show them as new files yet to be added to the index.

---

Update Q4 2016:

> ### `commit`: fix empty commit creation when there's no changes but ita entries

(`ita` or `i-t-a` is "intent to add")

See [commit 2c49f7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c49f7ffb3063fdccccf2a038ab2eee66e7395e4), [commit 018ec3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/018ec3c8203ad1aee683840a580cfba7914419b6), [commit b42b451](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b42b45191950a4ac39f6f5ae042c15ad114da79b), [commit 425a28e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/425a28e0a4edfc39585cec6b0b6368c0ad9dbf7e) (24 Oct 2016) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6503602](https://github.com/git/git/commit/650360210afbd585f33ed622d3e700b1941b1ddb), 27 Oct 2016)</sup>

> When new paths were added by "`git add -N`" to the index, it was enough to circumvent the check by "`git commit`" to refrain from making an empty commit without "`--allow-empty`".
>   The same logic prevented "`git status`" to show such a path as "`new file`" in the "`Changes not staged for commit`" section.

[`git diff` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/650360210afbd585f33ed622d3e700b1941b1ddb/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L575-L581) now includes:

```
--ita-invisible-in-index:
```

> By default entries added by "`git add -N`" appear as an existing empty file in "`git diff`" and a new file in "`git diff --cached`".
>   This option makes the entry appear as a new file in "`git diff`" and non-existent in "`git diff --cached`".
>
> This option could be reverted with `--ita-visible-in-index`.
>
> Both options are experimental and could be removed in future.

---

Update Q1 2018 (Git 2.16.x/2.17), `git status` improves again.
"`git status`", after moving a path in the working tree (hence making
it appear "removed"), and then adding with the `-N` option (hence
making that appear "added") detected it as a rename, but did not
report the  old and new pathnames correctly.

See [commit 176ea74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/176ea747930908669200520ae14f9dbc61cf0d40), [commit 5134ccd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5134ccde642ae9ed6a244c92864c26734d100f4c), [commit ea56f97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea56f97749f6ded2b5d41c4c4ba41b53850b2872), [commit 98bc94e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98bc94ec79c789a70fe0b41bdc91b24ab8483063), [commit 06dba2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06dba2b0235293e84157a59fa22dc89baa336166), [commit 6de5aaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6de5aafdd12104df3d10ef54ac74723a41174290) (27 Dec 2017) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
Helped-by: [Igor Djordjevic (`boogisha`)](https://github.com/boogisha).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bc3dca0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc3dca07f435ed2ca5a974cdb0508f66cf442412), 23 Jan 2018)</sup>

Note: `i-t-a` or `ita` is "intended to add".

> ### `wt-status.c`: handle worktree renames
>
> Before [425a28e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/425a28e0a4edfc39585cec6b0b6368c0ad9dbf7e) (diff-lib: allow ita entries treated as "not yet exist
>   in index" - 2016-10-24, Git 2.11.0-rc0) there are never "new files" in the index, which essentially disables rename detection because we only detect renames when a new file appears in a diff pair.
>
> After that commit, an i-t-a entry can appear as a new file in "`git diff-files`".
>   But the diff callback function in `wt-status.c` does not handle this case and produces incorrect status output.

---

Update Q4 2018 with Git 2.20, `git status` avoid displaying multiple renames on the same target.

See [commit 3e73cc6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e73cc62c0d80fedd1fc612e256b5eb3f3068de4) (27 Sep 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 98f3f00](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98f3f007f520de518c732c74085234dede144926), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `commit`: fix erroneous BUG, 'multiple renames on the same target? how?'
>
> `builtin/commit.c:prepare_to_commit()` can call `run_status()` twice if
>   using the editor, including status, and the user attempts to record a
>   non-merge empty commit without explicit `--allow-empty`.
>   If there is also a rename involved as well (due to using 'git add -N'), then a BUG in `wt-status.c` is triggered:
>
> BUG: wt-status.c:476: multiple renames on the same target? how?
>
> The reason we hit this bug is that both `run_status()` calls use the same
>   `struct wt_status * (named s)`, and `s->change` is not freed between runs.
>   Changes are inserted into `s` with `string_list_insert`, which usually means
>   that the second run just recomputes all the same results and overwrites
>   what was computed the first time.